# I have a form I created and it looks great in all browsers but Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

My form on this page http://fashiondevelopmentgroup.com/
In the sidebar ENJOY OUR FREE NEWSLETTER is not looking right in Firefox. Everywhere else it is fine. Is there a way to code CSS specific to Firefox to fix this?
I have used the -moz-margin-start to set the horizontal css, but is there a specific vertical code for Firefox?
Thanks,
Brian

here is my code:

```
input, textarea, select {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #889291;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -55px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #889291;
    -moz-margin-start:67%; 
    -webkit-margin-start:70%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="optin">
    <form action="http://fashiondevelopmentgroup.us2.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?                             u=1eed93a2e1bb3dc00d80e42af&id=25ea8ae595"; method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"    name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" style="background-   image:url('HERE IS WHERE YOU WILL PUT THE LINK TO YOUR IMAGE THAT YOU    UPLOADED');background-repeat: no-repeat; width:300px; height:151px;" novalidate>
        <input type="email" size="30" value="Email Address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
            <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: is there anyway you can put the button input in the same container as the text input...that would relieve you...mind you IE is breaking (most if all)

Comment: not really sure how I'd do that without breaking the form itself.  What were you thinking and how would I move it like that?

Answer (score 0):

in your my_style.css line 8 you have a 50px margin-top for all input, textarea, and select elements.  get rid of that so you can style individually for your situation.
then add `position:relative` you the parent div of the submit button. then add `position:absolute; top:0;right:0;` to your .button class..  this will align the button properly in firefox as well.
You will no longer need those margins in the .button class either. use the value in top: and right: to move the button exactly where you want it

Comment: This works great thanks Chris.  The only thing is if you look at firefox compared to the other browsers the SIGN UP button is about 1px lower than the others.  So you see the box behind it.